# Counting recurring instances without a map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to write a heuristic engine of sorts in JavaScript that essentially reads all elements and their children, hashes the hierarchy of tags, and then finds which hashes are most often repeating, so as to detect elements of the page that would correspond to each post on your Facebook newsfeed or each Reddit submission on the page.

Normally when I'm tasked with something like this, I would use a Map object that indexed the hash as the key and then stored the amount of times it has been found as the value, but it seems that this functionality is disabled by default in most browsers, and this is a script that I would like to release to the public when finished.

Because of this, I am looking for a way to be able to count each hash and store that data in a way that can be accessed without a huge performance overhead. Since Map seems to not be an option for now, what are my workarounds?

Comment: just use a plain object.

Comment: Post the not-working-code so we can understand what exactly are you trying t do!